# Why is the data not being written to the file?

Tags: node.js, file, stream, createwritestream

I am trying to create a file with dummy data. Since the file will be huge with 32^5 data points, I was using the write-stream. But I cannot see any data being written to the file. What could be the reason for this?

```
const faker = require('faker');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');

const MAX_DATA_POINTS = Math.pow(32, 5)

const stream = fs.createWriteStream('sample-data.csv', { flags : 'a' });

for(let i = 0; i < MAX_DATA_POINTS; i++) {
        console.log(i)
        stream.write(`${faker.name.findName()}, ${i} ${os.EOL}`);
}

console.log(`Written ${MAX_DATA_POINTS} .. `);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `write` method returns `false` if the *stream* wishes for the calling code to wait for the **drain** event to be emitted before continuing to write additional data and true otherwise. It is quite possible that the stream is not draining, and calls to `write()` are just buffering chunks and returning **false**.

You will need to wait till all the **buffered chunks** are drained (accepted for delivery by the operating system). When that happens, the drain event will be emitted.

**Note:** It is recommended that once write() returns false, no more chunks be written until the 'drain' event is emitted.

You could modify your dummy-csv file creator code in the way I have given.

```
const faker = require('faker');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');

const MAX_DATA_POINTS = Math.pow(32, 5);
let c = 0;

const stream = fs.createWriteStream('sample-data.csv', { flags : 'a' });

function write() {

    let ok = true;
    do {
        c++;
        ok = stream.write(`${faker.name.findName()}, ${c} ${os.EOL}`);
    } while (c < MAX_DATA_POINTS && ok);

    if(c < MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
        stream.once('drain', write)
    }

}


write()
```